# Tell where the showEvent is from

Tags: qt, qt4, qtabwidget

I have a QTabWidget, and I defined showEvent for one of the child widget.

Now how can I know where the showEvent is from?

It could be:

1. Switched from other tabs
2. The current index of tabwidget was not changed, the whole window just become visible

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QShowEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qshowevent.html) is very generic, so there's no direct way to get information about what triggered it. Depending on your needs either save current value of [QTabWidget::currentIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) between show events or move your logic to `QTabWidget::currentChanged` slot.